# October CMS | Using a button to send email retrieved from a field

Tags: php, laravel, forms, octobercms

I'm trying to dynamically find email address (from what has been inputted in a field), then sending out email to that address.

So far, I have been able to get the button to send emails but unable to retrieve the address from model.

Examples:

Controller

```
public function onSend()

{  
   // Retrieve email address from Machines model in email field
   $this->vars['email'] = Machines::get('email');

   // Send to email address using partial button
   Mail::send('martin.maintenance::mail.maintenancereminder', [], function($message) {
      $message->to($this->vars['email']);
   });
}
```

Field (in Machines model)

```
email:
  label: 'Email Address'
  span: auto
  type: text
  tab: Details
```

Partial (button)

```
<button
    type="submit"
    data-request="onSend"
    class="btn btn-primary">
    Reminder
</button>
```

Error
[image]

Happy to provide any additional info. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what part of your code is triggering that error, but I suspect it has something to do with what `::get('email')` is returning.

`Machines::get('email')` returns a Collection of `Machines` instances like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#4744
  all: [
    App\Models\Machines {#4745
      email: "example@example.com",
    },
    App\Models\Machines {#4746
      email: "example2@example.com",
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If you want all of the `email` column values in an Array/Collection, do this:

```php
$this->vars['email'] = Machines::pluck('email');
```

`Machines::pluck('email')` returns a Collection of `strings` like this:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#4516
  all: [
    "example@example.com",
    "example2@example.com",
    // ...
  ]
}
```

If you explictly need an array, you can do:

```
$this->vars['email'] = Machines::pluck('email')->toArray();
/*
 * [
 *   "example@example.com",
 *   "example2@example.com",
 *   // ...
 * ]
 */
```

Also, sidenote, Model names in Laravel are by convention singular, so it should be `Machine` instead of `Machines`.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm still getting the error with ->pluck('email'); Is there a way I can dump the variables from the controller to see the data being returned?

Comment: Yup! You can use `dump($variable)` to print them out, or `dd($variable)` to print them and end execution (easier for in-browser inspection of your variables).

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! I have managed to get it working now :)

$this->vars['email'] = Machines::all()->where('id', '=', $myId)->pluck('email')->toArray();

Comment: Nice! 1 suggestion though; `Machines::all()` will load _every row in your database into memory_ before filtering to a single record via `->where('id', '=', $myId)`, which you then pluck into an array of a single Email. You can literally just do: `$this->vars['email'] = Machines::find($myId)->email;`. If you **need** an array of 1 email, then: `$this->vars['email'] = [Machines::find($myId)->email];`.

Comment: That's great advice thank you!

One last thing I need your help with please.. The method to get the ID when updating  a record, doesn't work when viewing as columns (index) as the ID's are not part of the URL. How do I tell the controller what the record ID's are for each record? I realise I may not make much sense, it's hard to describe. 

I thank you for all your help!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, from that description I'm not too sure. Typically, you either identify the ID in the URL like `/model/{id}/action` (where `action` can be `show`, `edit`, `update`, etc.), or you send it as a Query String/Post Field, both via `<input name="id" type="hidden" value="{{ $model->id }}"/>` (or similar). `request()->input('id')` would have the value of `$model->id`. If you're still unsure, feel free to ask a new question 